# How can I use a C linked list from Perl XS?

Tags: perl, linked-list, xs

I writing programing with Perl and XS. I need to display and do some operations that use a  linked list from C. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to say you could have provided a bit more information to make it easier for people to help you.

Anyway. Despite the age, I would suggest you look at the [CookBookA](http://search.cpan.org/~dmr/CookBookA-19960430/) and [CookBookB](http://search.cpan.org/~dmr/CookBookB-19960430/) examples in Dean Roehrich's CPAN directory. Specifically, in the CookBookB set, you will find an example that does exactly what you ask for: 'ListOfStruct'.

Answer (score 2):

Write a C function to serialize the linked list as a string, or better yet write a set of functions: new_list, destroy_list, add_item, remove_item, walk_list (should take a function reference and call it on each item in the list).  Then you could say things like:

```
my $list = $new_list;
add_item $list, 5;
add_item $list, 6;
add_item $list, 7;
walk_list $list, sub { print $_[0] }; #prints 567
destroy_list $list;
```

Answer (score 0):

[perldoc Inline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline)